# LaTex: IEEEtran "\title{ title }" doesn't show

Tags: latex, ieee

I'm practicing LaTeX with IEEEtran.cls. I'm am slowly filling in the information, but I am getting stuck from the beginning.

```
\documentclass[12pt, journal, compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\title{ This is my practice document}
\author{Yui}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract content goes here.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

From the above simple .tex file, after compilation in the PDF, I can see the Abstract content. However, I don't see either title or author.

Any suggestions? Please and thank you.

Comment: Duplicate posted: [`IEEEtran` `\title{ * }` does not show](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137344/5764)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was cross posted on tex.stackexchange.com, where it is better on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hawk_08 is pretty much correct, but I'll post the completed tex because you appear to have misunderstood him.

```
\documentclass[12pt, journal, compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\title{ This is my practice document}
\author{Yui}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract content goes here.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Notice the `\maketitle` after the `\author` command

Comment: Oh, it's working. Should I understand '\maketitle' as a comment which "activates" \title, \author and etc ?

Comment: @ElectroJunkie Pretty much.. make title is the command that actually creates the fancy title. I would guess that multiple commands make use of the data you passed in via the author and title commands.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can see you are missing is the \maketitle after further research on the IEEEtran paper I have the make title should go after the \end{abstract}. Also if you need further reference you can go [here](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf). Also I found that the pre-filled form given by IEEE were pretty good you can find them [here](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it didn't work.

Comment: Heh, I just didn't know how to use it properly, apparently :)

Comment: @ElectroJunkie we all start somewhere!